# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pesel'

Tags: django

I'm new with django. I'm really confused with views.

Here is my models.py

```
class Pacjent(models.Model):
name= models.CharField(max_length=30)
surname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
pesel = models.ForeignKey(Pesel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
birth = models.DateField(datetime.date)
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def pacjent_view(request):
obj =Pacjent.objects.all()
context={'pesele': obj.pesel}
return render(request,'PrzychodniaZdrowia/kartapacjenta.html',context)
```

An error is displayed when trying to start: "Exception Value:
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pesel'".
What is wrong with this code? How do I display this model on the website?

Comment: What is `obj.persel` supposed to do? Note that `obj` is a *collection* of `Pacjent` objects, not a single `Pacjent` object.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass it to template in this way:

```
context = {"query": obj}
```

and than handle it in your template:

```
{% for obj in query %}
{{ obj.pesele }}
{% endfor %}
```